# Need help with text box input

Tags: c#, validation, mask

It's actually a grid column but it functions just like a textbox. I need it to be able to accept numbers only, but it has to be able to accept numbers with leading 0's. What would I use as a mask to get this result? If I do any kind of numeric mask then it will cut off the leading 0's, eg 002456841. If I don't use a numeric mask, then characters will be accepted which is unacceptable.

Am I not thinking outside of the box enough with this? I was also thinking like maybe instead of a mask using a loop or something to make sure it's only numbers and erase/pop up a message if it's not...but I just don't know, I would rather just have the box so it only accepts numbers but any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using a RegEx '\d{1,10}' but it was still not working, I had the data type in the setters and getters as an int which wasn't working, so I set it as string and then parsed/cast it as an int when I needed to use it that way which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just read each key press and reject any that fall outside of your range. Implementation depends on if this is a web grid or a windows/wpf grid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have couple options here:

- First, use a regular expression to validate
- Second, use a jQuery's Masked input plugin.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo

**Updated Text**
hmm, I am not sure why will you have to use Java, I was just suggesting you to try use the jQuery plugin with a regular expression to mask with. I think that should solve your issue... also if you have doubts on your regex then you can always test it through 
http://www.regextester.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been trying a regular expression and it still deletes the 0's,\\d{1,10}, it is an int type though. Also - I'm not using java...

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in asp.net webforms (you didn't say which platform/language), then you can use the MS Ajax filteredTextBox extender, which lets you specify what can be entered.  It connects to an asp.net TextBox and when a not allowed character key is pressed, nothing happens.

I'd suggest a bit more information in your questions if you want specific answers.  Especially what platform/language your working in.  C# is rather broad, and isn't mentioned in your question or title, just as a tag.